# Make scaffold deploy only changed helm charts

Tags: microservices, kubernetes-helm, monorepo, skaffold

I have several helm deployments in the same repo and am using skaffold to build and deploy them.
I've broken up the skaffold config in different parts (aka modules with different `metadata.name`) so that I can refer to those that I want to deploy using the `--module=[]` flag.

My question is how to detect which helm charts have changed so that I can deploy only those.